# Updating items in a ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I am using the `ObjectListView` control in my application. Every 1 second, I have a timer that ticks, and refreshes a `List` of type `TransferMetrics` (`List<TransferMetrics> activeTransfers`). My `TransferMetrics` class looks like this;

```
class TransferMetrics
{
    public Guid guid { get; set; }
    public string jobName {get; set;}
    public int TotalTransferred {get; set;}
    public int TotalToTransfer { get; set; }
    public int TotalFailed { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStarted { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    //Used for single file uploads only
    public double percentage { get; set; }
    public int cps { get; set; }

    //used for database transfers
    public string dbPath { get; set; }
    public bool restoreDatabase { get; set; }
    public string dbName { get; set; }
    public DocsToTransferBundle docsBundle { get; set; }
    public bool databaseRestored {get; set;}
    public bool dbRestoreInProgress { get; set; }

    public List<FailedUploadsBundle> FailedUploadDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Every 1 second, I want to update the `ObjectListView` to add any new items that don't exist in the control already, and update those that already do. The unique identifier for each record is the `guid` property.

In my timer tick method,  I am calling the following code; `lvTransfers2.SetObjects(activeTransfers);`. This works, however it causes the control to "flash", i.e, remove all the items and re-draw them.

What is the elegant way to do what I am trying to achieve? I want any new instances in the `List` to be added to the control, and any existing items to be updated.

My second attempt was this;

```
    var at = uploadManager.GetTransferMetrics();

    foreach(var a in at)
    {
        var item = activeTransfers.Where(x => x.guid == a.guid).FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
        {
            lvTransfers2.UpdateObject(item);
            //item = a;
        }
        else
        {
            activeTransfers.Add(a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about UpdateObject()? - "Update the given model object into the ListView. The model will be added if it doesn't already exist.". By default, the OLV checks the model objects equality by reference, so make sure you keep working with the same instances. There also is UpdateObjects(), so maybe you could just add the new item to your List<> and feed that to UpdateObjects() when it changed.

Comment: Using UpdateObjects() causes new entries to be added every time the timer ticks.

Comment: Then you probably keep creating new instances of the items/list?! Maybe there is a way to implement a custom equality comparer for the OLV so you can use your guid.

Comment: `List<TransferMetrics> activeTransfers = new List<TransferMetrics>();` is defined as a global variable in the form class. The list is then updated on the timer tick using `activeTransfers = uploadManager.GetTransferMetrics();`

Comment: Thats probably why it won't work. GetTransferMetrics() probably creates a whole new set of TransferMetrics. You have to override the Equals() method in your TransferMetrics class and use the Guid for example to determine if two objects of that kind are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can first bind a list to objectlistview

```
if (classes == null) classes = new List<myClass>();
            objectListView1.SetObjects(classes);
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();
```

in your timer's tick event you must add new object to list and build the list:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myClass class1 = new myClass();
            class1.Description = i.ToString();
            classes.Add(class1);

            objectListView1.BuildList(true);

            ++i;
        }
```

I'd checked it and its not flashing each time. Hope this helps

Comment: This isn't quite working. I am setting my List of objects by doing the following; `activeTransfers = uploadManager.GetTransferMetrics();` `GetTransferMetrics` returns a `List<TransferMetrics>`. So rather than `activeTransfers` being added to like your example above, `activeTransfers` is assigned to directly.

Comment: objectlistview.setobjects will rebuild entire list which you can observe on the screen while olv.buildlist() just do it silently. Did you try using objectListView1.SetObjects(activeTransfers); once then activeTransfers = uploadManager.GetTransferMetrics(); and objectListView1.BuildList(true); on timer event?

Comment: Yeah I did, and it doesn't work - the items are never added to the listview. I guess that must be a limitation of the ObjectListView.

Comment: Check this. Its ugly though but should work. classes.RemoveRange(0, classes.Count());
            classes.AddRange(GetList());
            objectListView1.BuildList();

Comment: That works, however when I click the item in the control, as the timer ticks, it still does the "flashing" behavior, i.e. it becomes unhighted when it's clicked.

Comment: Fixed it. I was creating a new List in the `GetTransferMetrics` method! Oops :)

Comment: Glad to hear!! may be you can mark your question as answered.. Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

Probably a bit late but I ran into this issue too and I found out that

```
 lvTransfers2.UpdateObject(item);
```

does not always refresh the listview. However this works all the time:

```
 lvTransfers2.RefreshObject(item);
```

RefreshObject(..) will add the item if necessary and otherwise refresh the row with the contents of the passed object.